Shadows of the Halo

I hover above where the sun can't hide,
A fiery glow, stretching far and wide.
Atop the head, I mark a line,
Where bones meet, a boundary fine.


In structures tall, I take my place,
Above, a feature, flat in space.
A fringe I form in creatures small,
Helping some to swim or crawl.


In plants I linger, soft and bright,
A feature on petals, out of sight.
I circle the earth, unseen but clear,
A tiny force, spreading fear.


What am I, this presence wide,
That lurks unseen, though far and wide?


This looks like a

 corona

I hover above where the sun can't hide, A fiery glow, stretching far and wide.

  the luminous plasma outer atmosphere of the Sun, most easily seen during a solar eclipse.

Atop the head, I mark a line, Where bones meet, a boundary fine.

 A region of the skull between the frontal bone and the two parietal bones.

In structures tall, I take my place, Above, a feature, flat in space.

 A large chandelier, to hold candles or lamps, hung from the roof of a church.

A fringe I form in creatures small, Helping some to swim or crawl.

 In zoology, an annular ciliated organ used for locomotion.

In plants I linger, soft and bright, A feature on petals, out of sight.

 A crown-like structure between the petals and stamens in some flowers

I circle the earth, unseen but clear, A tiny force, spreading fear.

  Perhaps a name for the Coronavirus which caused a pandemic.

